# calculating player statistics from database

Tags: mysql, database

i have the following tables.

[image: database tables]

i want to fetch all the player statistics record from the given tables, the records of individual player includes.

1. Player Name
2. Position
3. Total Number of games played
4. Number of goals scored
5. Total number of assist for goals.
6. Total Points (total goals + total assist = total points).

after trying i came up with this query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as player_name,
    p.position, 
    COUNT(g.id)
FROM 
    gce_player p 
LEFT JOIN 
    gce_user u ON(u.id = p.user_id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    gce_game_team_lineup gtl ON(gtl.player_id = p.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    gce_game_team gt ON(gt.id = gtl.game_team_id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    gce_game_goal gg ON(gg.player_id = p.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    gce_game g ON(g.id = gt.game_id) 
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.id asc
```

the above query returns me proper record till total number of games played, i am facing issue fetching the proper records after this, ill appreciate any kind of help on this.

here is the link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3031f/6) if you want to look at the schema, i have added some test data too.

thank you.

**UPDATE :**

> here are few of the rules to remember.
>
> 1. Number of goals scored = total number of goals scored by a player.    for example if in `gce_game_goal` table there are 10 rows which have
>      the value of `player_id as 4` it means the player have scored 10 goals
>      and i need to fetch this record for individual player,     and
>      likewise if there are 7 rows in which player_id have value of 3 this
>      means player with id 3 have scored 7 goals and likewise.
> 2. Total number of assist for goals = total number of assist given to a goalie by a player (assist is like a pass in football).    i need to
>      calculate total number of assist or pass that was done by a user.
>      for each goal there will be two assist, and each assist are players
>      who pass the ball to a golaie.    i want to count the number of passes
>      or assist given by a player.    for example if in `gce_game_goal`
>      table there are 8 rows or records that have the value of 3 in either
>      assis1_id or assist2_id column, this means player with id 3 have
>      scored 8 assist in total

.

kindly let me know if you still have any doubts/question, ill try to improve my question

Thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Which value, what do you expect, what is returned? Are there errors, which ones?

Comment: What is `Total number of assist for goals.` ?

Comment: sorry guys for having confused you, i am updating my question with all the details, please hold for few minutes, thanks.

Comment: Are you only working with a database?  Do you have access to a server like C++ even PHP?  I can only imagine how slow that last query is once you have about 50 rows per table.  If so, I recommend you handle your computation there.  It's easier and faster.  More lines of code though, but you'll probably spend the same time making esoteric queries like those work.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy i am using PHP.  `I recommend you handle your computation there.` what do you mean by this?

Comment: Please add `php` tag, and I'll give full answer, but I warn you that I will be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is caused by aggregating along multiple different dimensions of the data (say by game and by goal).  This results in a cross product for each player.

A fairly general solution is to do aggregations in the `from` clause, along each dimension.  Each variable (or perhaps a few variables) comes from a different aggregation:

```
select u.last_name, u.first_name, p.position, 
       pg.goals, pg.assists, (pg.goals + pg.assists) as TotalPoints
from gce_player p join
     gce_user u
     on p.user_id = u.id left outer join
     (select player_id, SUM(goal) as goals, SUM(assist) as assists
      from ((select player_id, 1 as goal, 0 as assist
             from gce_game_goal
            ) union all
            (select assist1_id, 0 as goal, 1 as assist
             from gce_game_goal
            ) union all
            (select assist2_id, 0 as goal, 1 as assist
             from gce_game_goal
            )
           ) t
      group by player_id
     ) pg
     on pg.player_id = p.id left outer join
     (select gtl.player_id, count(*) as NumTeams
      from gce_game_team_lineup gtl join
           gce_game_team gt
           on gtl.id = gt.team_id
     ) g
     on g.player_id = p.id
```

Comment: the query is not working, and i am not able to make out the errors, if you would want to test your query against the test data here is the link to sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3031f/6 BTW thank you for your response.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar . . . I fixed the problems.  However, less important than the particular syntax is the idea.  You need to calculate the various statistics at the player level *before* joining them together.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as player_name,
    count(g.id) as Goals,
    (select 
            count(*)
        from
            gce_game_goal
        where
            assist1_id = p.player_id) 
    +(select 
            count(*)
        from
            gce_game_goal
        where
            assist2_id = p.player_id) as Assists,
     count(g.id) 
     + (select 
            count(*)
        from
            gce_game_goal
        where
            assist1_id = p.player_id) 
     + (select 
            count(*)
        from
            gce_game_goal
        where
            assist2_id = p.player_id) as Total
FROM
    gce_player as p
LEFT JOIN
    gce_game_goal as g ON p.id = g.player_id
LEFT JOIN 
    gce_user u ON(u.id =p.user_id)
GROUP BY p.player_id
```

Comment: this gives me error, you can try the query by yourself in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3031f/6